# What is the logic behind validating a user entity with Microsft Graph/Azure AD as the the authenticator of my API?

Tags: azure, security, oauth, azure-active-directory

I already made the authentication flow with the Microsoft Graph/Azure AD authentication. Once I get the authenticated user's token I store them in his cookies. To validate the user's token I call the Microsft Graph API resource `/me`. This does not seem a good approach because basically everytime time a client does a request to my API, he is basically doing 2 requests because my API requests Azure AD for validation.

Is this a good flow?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.
Your front-end should acquire an access token for your API, which the API can verify using its digital signature.
The token will contain some info about the user as well as the app that acquired it.

The way in which the front-end acquires the token depends on the type of application.
Front-end single page apps use implicit grant flow for example.
Do note that you have to specifically ask for an access token for your API.

As long as your back-end is then configured with standard JWT Bearer authentication,
all is handled.
This is done by specifying the authority as your Azure AD tenant (or the common endpoint if it's multi-tenant),
and the standard bits for JWT authentication should download the public keys from Azure AD's metadata endpoint, which it can then use to verify validity of any access token it receives.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. So are you saying that I should generate a JWT token of my own? If so how can I, for example, access the user's photo without a Azure JWT token?

Comment: No, I mean you need to get a JWT from Azure AD that is meant for your API. Your API can exchange this token for another token with which you can then get the photo from e.g. MS Graph API.

Comment: So I need to store and handle refresh tokens from Azure in my backend? And doing requests depending on the user that tries to access my API?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to validate tokens for an api that's not yours (issued to your AppId Uri).

For example, Graph validates the tokens that are sent to it (issued for "https://graph.microsoft.com).

If you build and register in Azure AD an Api of your own (say AppIdUri="https://myapi.mydomain.com"), your clients will request and receive access tokens with aud claim set to "https://myapi.mydomain.com".

The clients themselves don't need to validate the access token issued for your Api But your Api, when it receives those access tokens, has to validate them. The validations, among other things will validate the access token was issued to "https://myapi.mydomain.com".

Try out this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation), to get a good understanding around concepts of token validation.

Comment: "Your Api, when it recieves those tokens, has to validate them". Can you tell me what to validate? If everything comes from Azure, how can I validate?